# Capacitor Voltage in Hodgkin Huxley model

Tags: voltage, capacitor, current

Skipping the whole discussion of the Hodgkin Huxley model (in the biomedical-neuronal domain), I have problems understanding the last step of this calculation (in pink):
[image]

Can anyone explain the transition to pink?
If you need more information I can provide it, but I would say the circuit is enough.

Answer (score 1):

The pink `=` is a lie there. What happens there is you have the differential equation

$$
V_m(t) = R_mI + V_L - I_m \frac{\mathrm d\,V_m(t)}{\mathrm d\, t}$$

and differential equations of the form

$$y(t) = B - A \frac{\mathrm d\,y(t)}{\mathrm d\, t}, \quad\quad C, A\text{ const.} $$

are called *linear first order ordinary differential equations*, and they always have the same closed form solution (if any). Your specific green box just seems to be that (\$y(t) := V_m(t), A:=I_m,\ldots\$), with all the variables expanded (there seems to be a relation between \$I_m\$ and \$1/\tau\$). Can't really follow that derivation either, mostly because I don't understand your notation.

Comment: Thank you for your reply! In your reply, 'Im' is actually the time constant 'tau' (I have bad handwriting)

Comment: that's fine, right, because it's a constant factor; doesn't matter whether we call it \$I_m\$ or \$\tau_m\$.

Answer (score 1):

It's the solution to a differential equation. It appears the \$\ V_L\$ is supposed to be a constant voltage source. So it's an equivalent circuit to this, in more familiar form (and connecting one side to ground for convenience):

[image: schematic]

<sup>[simulate this circuit](/plugins/schematics?image=http%3a%2f%2fi.stack.imgur.com%2f6PjjL.png) – Schematic created using [CircuitLab](https://www.circuitlab.com/)</sup>

The final voltage will be \$V_L +  I\cdot R_m \$ and the time constant \$\tau_m\$ will be \$C_m \cdot R_m\$. And the initial condition in your equation is the capacitor voltage, which equals Vm, at t=0.

Comment: Thank you for your reply! It is much clearer now